# Objective-c NSRegularExpression strange match

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

My NSString pattern doesn't work well.

```
NSString *pattern = @"/api/v1/news/([0-9]+)/\\?categoryId=([0-9]+)";
NSString *string = urlString;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:nil];
```

Why it matches also the following string?

```
/api/v1/news/123/?categoryId=22abc
```

I want to match only

```
/api/v1/news/123/?categoryId=22
```

where 123 and 22 can be variable number.

Comment: Show the rest of the code, where you access the `NSTextCheckingResult`.

Comment: Slap a \b or $ on the end to make sure the path ends with one or more digits.

Comment: ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is fine, but it allows partial matches. To disallow them, use `^` and `$` anchors:

```
^/api/v1/news/([0-9]+)/\\?categoryId=([0-9]+)$
^                                            ^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ1gC9/1)

The `^` asserts the position at the beginning of string, and `$` asserts the position at the end of the string.

See also [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sApKvY) showing `NO MATCH` for the first input string you have, and [this demo](http://ideone.com/Kl6dXk) matching the second one.

If you need to match those strings as separate words, use `\\b` (word boundary) at the end and a `(?<!\\w)` look-behind (making sure there is no word character before) at the beginning:

```
(?<!\\w)/api/v1/news/([0-9]+)/\\?categoryId=([0-9]+)\\b
^^^^^^^^                                             ^^
```

If you need to access the captured texts, too, use something like:

```
NSString *pattern = @"^/api/v1/news/([0-9]+)/\\?categoryId=([0-9]+)$";
NSString *string = @"/api/v1/news/123/?categoryId=22";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string 
                            options:0 
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
NSLog(@"Group 1 number: %@", [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
NSLog(@"Group 2 number: %@", [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]]);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/AYHlfh), output is

```
Group 1 number: 123
Group 2 number: 22
```